# C# - How to Append a set of iterating text lines to a text line in a certain line?

Tags: c#, text, file-io, read-write

I need to append a set of iterating text lines to an already existing text file. How can i implement it using c#.

As an example-

Iterating text :

```
foreach (string toolName in value.Tools)
{
     sw.WriteLine("[\"at" + Count.ToString("D4") + "\"] = < ");
     sw.WriteLine("text = < \"" + toolName + "\" >");
     sw.WriteLine("description = <\" * \">");
     sw.WriteLine(">");
     Count++;
}
```

Should append it to the line 62 of myTextFile.txt

Comment: So you want to **Insert** some text at a certain line in a file?

Comment: Also what is this example you have given us, is this the **text** you want to **insert**

Comment: @TheGeneral yes. i need to add some text file which creates dynamically according to some values to a text file in line 62. But i need to append the text in that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. Add all your contents into a list of strings and then output to a file.

```
List<string> tools = new List<string>()
{
    "Hammer", "Wrench", "Screwdriver", "etc"
};

List<string> output = new List<string>();
int count = 1;
foreach ( string toolName in tools )
{
    if (output.Count ==  61)
    {
        output.Add ( "some string" );
        count++;
        continue;
    }
    output.Add ( "[\"at" + count.ToString ( "D4" ) + "\"] = < " );
    output.Add ( "[\"at" + count.ToString ( "D4" ) + "\"] = < " );
    output.Add ( "text = < \"" + toolName + "\" >" );
    output.Add ( "description = <\" * \">" );
    output.Add ( ">" );
    count++;
}

string path = @"C:\output.txt";
File.WriteAllLines ( path , output.ToArray ( ) );
```

Comment: how can i add this code to the line 62 of my existing file?

Comment: List<T> can be indexed, you can do output[61] = "some string"

Comment: @Gethma the essence of the solution to your problem has already been given. It is up to your to understand them and apply as appropriate. I will render you one more help on this since you are clearly very new to C#. If the line 62 is a hard requirement, you can put an **if** statement to detect line 62 and then use the **Insert** method to insert the string.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you between the ambiguity of this question, maybe you want something like this

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
lines.Insert(62,someFunkyText);
File.WriteAllLines(path,lines);
```

[ReadAllLines(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the
>   file.

[List.Insert(Int32, T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Insert_System_Int32__0_)

> Inserts an element into the List at the specified index.

[WriteAllLines(String, IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_WriteAllLines_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__)

> Creates a new file, writes a collection of strings to the file, and
>   then closes the file.